# Deleting a node from a skip list

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, implementation, skip-lists

I'm having some problems deleting a node from a skip list. I have the following structures:

```
struct Node
{
    int info;
    Node **link_;

    Node(int v, int levels)
    {
        info = v;
        link_ = new Node*[levels];

        for ( int i = 0; i < levels; ++i )
            link_[i] = NULL;
    }
};

struct List
{
    int H; // list height

    Node *Header;

    List()
    {
        Header = new Node(0, maxH);
        H = 1;
    }
};
```

The problem, I think, is in the function that searches for a node with a given value and then deletes it. The function is implemented like this:

```
void Remove(int v, List *L)
{
    Node *current = L->Header;

    for ( int i = L->H - 1; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        for ( ; current->link_[i] != NULL; current = current->link_[i] )
            if ( current->link_[i]->info > v )
                break;
            else if ( current->link_[i]->info == v )
            {
                // Node *del = current->link_[i];
                current->link_[i] = current->link_[i]->link_[i];

                // delete del;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

The function works fine as it is, however the list seems to break if I uncomment the two commented lines. By break I mean that the following test code never finishes:

```
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    List *SKL = new List();


    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
        Insert(rand() * rand(), SKL);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
        Search(rand() * rand(), SKL);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
        Remove(rand() * rand(), SKL);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
        Insert(rand() * rand(), SKL);


    return 0;
}
```

The problem lies in the last `for` loop that inserts more values in the list. If those two lines are commented out, the program finishes in about 10 seconds. If I uncomment them, it seems to enter an infinite loop as it doesn't even finish in minutes. I'm not sure if that's the right way of deleting a node from a skip list or not, so I'm posting my insertion function as well:

```
void Insert(int v, List *L)
{
    // this section just determines the levels the new node will be part of
    int newH = 0;

    int tmp;
    unsigned int rnd = rand() * rand(); 
    do
    {
        tmp = lookup[rnd & 255];
        rnd >>= 8;
        newH += tmp;
    } while ( tmp == 8 );

    if ( newH >= L->H )
        ++L->H;

    // this does the actual insertion
    Node *newNode = new Node(v, L->H);
    Node *current = L->Header;
    for ( int i = L->H - 1; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        for ( ; current->link_[i] != NULL; current = current->link_[i] )
            if ( current->link_[i]->info >= v )
                break;

        if ( i <= newH )
        {
            newNode->link_[i] = current->link_[i];
            current->link_[i] = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

So, my questions are:

1. Why does the program break, and how can I make it work while actually deleting the nodes I want to delete from memory?
2. Is this a correct way of implementing skip lists, or am I using a wrong approach?

Comment: It looks much like C, with some constructors. You could make use of the destructor of a node to remap automatically the "previous" to the "next" when the node is destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with the `Remove` method, as you guessed:

```
void Remove(int v, List *L)
{
    Node *current = L->Header;

    for ( int i = L->H - 1; i >= 0; --i )
    {
        for ( ; current->link_[i] != NULL; current = current->link_[i] )
        {
            if ( current->link_[i]->info > v )
            {
                break;
            }
            else if ( current->link_[i]->info == v )
            {
                // Node *del = current->link_[i];
                current->link_[i] = current->link_[i]->link_[i];

                // if (0 == i) delete del;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of example, let's assume that the node we wish to delete appears in 2 levels: 0 and 1.

The `for` loop on levels `L->H` to 2 does not do anything.

On level 1 it will find the node requested, and delete it.

On level 0, it will attempt to follow a pointer to the already deleted node, leading to undefined behavior.

Solution:

Only delete the node when at level 0. As long as your in a upper layer, the node is still referenced and you need to keep it alive.

Comment: This works, thanks. Won't this delete the node just from level 0 though? Shouldn't I delete it from all the levels? Or is that just not possible with this design?

Comment: The problem is: there is only one node, indexed from multiple levels. You need to remove all the references to it and then delete it (only once). Since you iterate over the levels in decreasing order, it is at the last level (0) that the actual deletion should occur.

Answer (score 0):

In your Remove function your outer loop iterates over the list for the count of the current number of entries. Then in the loop you remove one of those ntries but keep on iterating over the old count.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The count is the number of levels in the skip list. I iterate from the highest (fewer nodes) towards the lowest (all the nodes). Ideally I should decrement the count of levels if one level becomes empty, yes, but I don't understand how an empty level can cause an infinite loop. If it's empty, the inner loop hits NULL right away and the count gets decremented.